# Rounded corner in IE8, part of div overflowing to other div not visible

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners

I am trying to create some div (that should be buttons) that have rounded corner. I can get that to work using border-radius.htc or PIE.htc.

I position them using margin-top. The part of the button that flows over to the other div below is not visible, which it should be. Check screenshot:

[image]

```
.menu_buttons{
       margin-top:45px;
       overflow: visible;
       margin-left: 10px;
       width: 85px;
       height: 3em;
       vertical-align: middle; 
       float:left;
       cursor: pointer;
       text-align: center;
       font: 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

       border-radius: 10px;
       behavior: url(PIE.htc);

}
```

.diagonal:

```
.diagonal{

    background-image: linear-gradient(left top, #CFD993 30%, #8DA900 68%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #CFD993 30%, #8DA900 68%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left top, #CFD993 30%, #8DA900 68%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg left top, #CFD993 30%, #8DA900 68%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #CFD993 30%, #8DA900 68%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left top, #CFD993 30%, #8DA900 68%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#CFD993', endColorstr='#8DA900', GradientType=1); 
    /*background: #CFD993;*/


    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left top,
            right bottom,
            color-stop(0.3, #CFD993),
            color-stop(0.68, #8DA900)
    );

}
```

Part of my html:

```
<div class="diagonal" id="section1">
        <img alt="SMIC Service Management In the Cloud" src="/images/smic_small.png" id="smic">        
        <div class="link_menu">
            <button class="menu_buttons ui-corner-all smic_green" id="overview">Overview</button>
            <!--Some more <div....-->
            <button class="menu_buttons ui-corner-all smic_green" id="usage_benchmark">SMICloud<br>usage<br>benchmark</button>            
            <a class="menu_items" id="get_smic">Get SMICloud</a>
            <!--Some more <a....-->
            <a class="menu_items" id="contact">Contact</a>
         </div>  

    </div>
```

Adding following to .diagonal changes the look according to below screenshot:

```
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
```

[image]

When trying to add z-index -10 to the div below #section1, nothing happens.

I am totally stuck. How can I do this, creating a div with rounded corner that overflow to another div?

Comment: I'd recommend [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) as the best solution for rounded corners in IE. It also uses a HTC file as does the one in your example, but it's easily the best one out there. Plus it also deals with CSS box shadows and gradients too. Also, if you still have problems, the CSS3Pie website has some good tips on avoiding common issues.

Comment: Just tried it as well. I made some changes to above, instead of using relative position, I tried positioning the divs (which now are buttons) using margin-tops and now I can position it properly. The problem now is that the buttons are only visible in #section1, it's cut and not visible where it flows over to the div below (overflow:visible; doesn't help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate you definitions, to prevent odd behaviors and save debugging time.

Without the remaining `CSS` for the elements you've provided, you can see a working example, fully tested across all mentioned browsers, using your definitions for the `div.menu_buttons`:

See this [Working Example!](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10767421/border-radius.html)

**CSS**

```
.curved {
  -moz-border-radius:10px;        /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;     /* Safari and chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius:10px;      /* Linux browsers */
  border-radius:10px;             /* CSS3 */
  behavior:url(border-radius.htc) /* Internet Explorer */
}

.menu_buttons {
  position:relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 60px;
  float:left;
  vertical-align: middle;    
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font: 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**EXAMPLE HTML**

```
<div class="menu_buttons curved">.menu_buttons element</div>
```

Download the [border-radius.htc](http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc), and check out the [CSS curved corner Demos and Page](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/) .

---

## TESTED ON

**Windows XP Profissional versão 2002 Service Pack 3**

- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 3.6.16
- Safari 5.1.2
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m
- K-Meleon 1.5.4

**Windows 7 Home Edition Service Pack 1**

- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.164211C
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 12.0
- Safari 5.1.4
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m

**Linux Ubuntu 12.04**

- Firefox 12.0
- Chromium 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux)

---

## EDITED

Related to OPs comment regarding the mandatory appliance of `CSS` `position`.

[Working example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10767421/border-radius-no-position.html) for the div with rounded corners with **no `position` set**!

---

## EDITED

The Final Fix after some chatting was the proper declaration of CSS `position` for the elements wrapper and the elements then selves.

The [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/uBhuC/) with the correct `CSS` declarations!

Comment: Thanks, I did check all this out. And as mentioned I did get it working as well. What I realize now is that when I remove all position:relative; from all parents except body, then it works. Don't think it's related to that it lays over another div. Updating my question. This is in direct contradiction to the instructions for the component.

Comment: @Nicsoft, check me answer for the EDITED part were you have a link to the same solution without the use of CSS `position`.

Comment: Seems like we do things in parallel :) Check my updated answer, I do like that now. Facing another problem, updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Nicsoft, you keep updating your question with a new problem, that's bad usage of SackOverflow... Nonetheless, do you have a link or can you place a screen-shot to the new issue?

Comment: Sorry about that, will not do like that again. I added a screen shot in my post.

Comment: @Nicsoft, I assume that your buttons are inside `div.diagonal`, can you update your question with that element `CSS` ?

Comment: Updated! Please note that I had some z-index which I removed and that changed the look, so I updated my screenshot. Sorry for messing around...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11781/discussion-between-zuul-and-nicsoft)